# connecting database to flutter application

Tags: flutter, database-connection

I'm currently developing a mobile application using the Flutter framework, and I need guidance on connecting my app to an MS SQL database. After researching available resources, I noticed that many examples use PHP and MySQL for backend connections. However, I want to confirm if PHP can also work with MS SQL and if so, how would i obtain the username, key and link to the database

Comment: Please add some few lines of code of what you've tried.

Comment: i did not start my coding process yet, but i wanted to check if using a different database host would still work, and if there is more to the process than just connecting backend.

Comment: @kawthar If that's the case, then this question is not answerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, this would run so that your backend takes over the data management and processing regarding the sql database. Your Flutter app communicates with the backend via an interface, in most cases via REST.

Your POST, PUT, PATCH, etc. requests you send via Rest are intercepted by the backend and managed accordingly. PHP is not a must, you can use any language for this, e.g. Go or Java.

Most languages have appropriate frameworks to interact with the database. Here a simple Google search is enough, but most languages should already have something like that.